# Portable External vs External Desktop Hard Drives

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, portable-harddrive

What are the differences between a desktop(the bigger not so portable USB cases) and portable USB drives. Is it basically 2.5" vs 3.5" drives, or are there any other major benefits besides size and maybe performance?

Comment: the bigger ones have the advantage of being large, so you are less likely to move them from a secure location, and in the process significantly increasing their likely lifetime and reliability. As a general rule, pre-assembled external drives use cheaper hard disks than you would be likely to use if you bought the parts to assemble your own, but will likely cost you a little more.

Comment: We talking about eSATA external drives or USB 3.0 external drives?

Comment: USB 3 drives. Curious as to pros/cons

Answer (score 1):

A lot of it comes down to the the type of drive inside the portal USB enclosure. Standard portable drives are often not as fast as you would purchase to put inside your machine. However, you can get enclosures with fast hard drives and USB3 (if your PC supports it) that would provide relatively similar performance.

This is assuming you don't start involving Solid State drives, which are a class all their own.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just take and compare desktop and portable drives (don't try to compare portable SSD with desktop HDD;) There are various parameters which you must look at while comparing such as **cache**, **interface**, real **read-write** speeds, **latency** and so on.
And benchmarks like [this](http://www.tomshardware.com/charts/hdd-charts-2013/benchmarks,134.html) (for desktop HDD) and [this](http://www.tomshardware.com/charts/external-hard-drive-charts/benchmarks,26.html) (for portable) can help you.

However if we take the same price category, portable usually has **less performance, lower voltage, less capacity** or **higher price** than a desktop drive.